# pandas.read_excel error when using usecols

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, python-unicode, pandas-datareader

I am having some problem in reading data from an Excel file.
The Excel file contains column names with unicode characters.

I need, because of some automation reasons, to pass the *usecols* argument to the pandas.read_excel function.

The thing is that when I don't use the *usecols* argument the data is loaded with no errors.

Here's the code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(file)
df.colums

Index([u'col1', u'col2', u'col3', u'col with unicode à', u'col4'], dtype='object')
```

If I use usecols:

```
COLUMNS = ['col1', 'col2', 'col with unicode à']
df = pd.read_excel(file, usecols = COLUMNS)
```

I receive the following error:

```
ValueError: Usecols do not match columns, columns expected but not found: ['col with unicode \xc3\xa0']
```

Using `encoding = 'utf-8'` as argument of read_excel does not solve the problem, and also encoding the COLUMNS elements.

EDIT: Here the complete error window.

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-541ccb88da6a> in <module>()
      2 df = pd.read_excel(file)
      3 cols = df.columns
----> 4 df = pd.read_excel(file, usecols = ['col1', 'col2', 'col with unicode à'])

C:\Users\GiacomoSachs\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.pyc in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    186                 else:
    187                     kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
--> 188             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    189         return wrapper
    190     return _deprecate_kwarg

C:\Users\GiacomoSachs\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.pyc in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    186                 else:
    187                     kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
--> 188             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    189         return wrapper
    190     return _deprecate_kwarg

C:\Users\GiacomoSachs\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.pyc in read_excel(io, sheet_name, header, names, index_col, parse_cols, usecols, squeeze, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skiprows, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, verbose, parse_dates, date_parser, thousands, comment, skip_footer, skipfooter, convert_float, mangle_dupe_cols, **kwds)
    373         convert_float=convert_float,
    374         mangle_dupe_cols=mangle_dupe_cols,
--> 375         **kwds)
    376 
    377 

C:\Users\GiacomoSachs\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.pyc in parse(self, sheet_name, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, converters, true_values, false_values, skiprows, nrows, na_values, parse_dates, date_parser, thousands, comment, skipfooter, convert_float, mangle_dupe_cols, **kwds)
    716                                   convert_float=convert_float,
    717                                   mangle_dupe_cols=mangle_dupe_cols,
--> 718                                   **kwds)
    719 
    720     @property

C:\Users\GiacomoSachs\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.pyc in parse(self, sheet_name, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, dtype, true_values, false_values, skiprows, nrows, na_values, verbose, parse_dates, date_parser, thousands, comment, skipfooter, convert_float, mangle_dupe_cols, **kwds)
    599                                     usecols=usecols,
    600                                     mangle_dupe_cols=mangle_dupe_cols,
--> 601                                     **kwds)
    602 
    603                 output[asheetname] = parser.read(nrows=nrows)

C:\Users\GiacomoSachs\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.pyc in TextParser(*args, **kwds)
   2154     """
   2155     kwds['engine'] = 'python'
-> 2156     return TextFileReader(*args, **kwds)
   2157 
   2158 

C:\Users\GiacomoSachs\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.pyc in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    893             self.options['has_index_names'] = kwds['has_index_names']
    894 
--> 895         self._make_engine(self.engine)
    896 
    897     def close(self):

C:\Users\GiacomoSachs\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.pyc in _make_engine(self, engine)
   1130                                  ' "c", "python", or' ' "python-fwf")'.format(
   1131                                      engine=engine))
-> 1132             self._engine = klass(self.f, **self.options)
   1133 
   1134     def _failover_to_python(self):

C:\Users\GiacomoSachs\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.pyc in __init__(self, f, **kwds)
   2236         self._col_indices = None
   2237         (self.columns, self.num_original_columns,
-> 2238          self.unnamed_cols) = self._infer_columns()
   2239 
   2240         # Now self.columns has the set of columns that we will process.

C:\Users\GiacomoSachs\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.pyc in _infer_columns(self)
   2609                 columns = [names]
   2610             else:
-> 2611                 columns = self._handle_usecols(columns, columns[0])
   2612         else:
   2613             try:

C:\Users\GiacomoSachs\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.pyc in _handle_usecols(self, columns, usecols_key)
   2669                             col_indices.append(usecols_key.index(col))
   2670                         except ValueError:
-> 2671                             _validate_usecols_names(self.usecols, usecols_key)
   2672                     else:
   2673                         col_indices.append(col)

C:\Users\GiacomoSachs\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.pyc in _validate_usecols_names(usecols, names)
   1235         raise ValueError(
   1236             "Usecols do not match columns, "
-> 1237             "columns expected but not found: {missing}".format(missing=missing)
   1238         )
   1239 

ValueError: Usecols do not match columns, columns expected but not found: ['col with unicode \xc3\xa0']
```

Comment: does it work if you pass the columns with indexing: `cols = df.columns` and then `df = pd.read_excel(file, usecols = cols[0,1,3])`?

Comment: @EdChum no, it gives the same error

Comment: This maybe a bug in the excel module, you could just drop the columns after loading or rename the cols in excel prior to loading if it becomes a persistent issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

first read the columns like

```
df = pd.read_excel(file, usecols="A:D")
```

where A:D is range of columns in excel you want to read then rename your columns like this

```
df.columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']
```

then access column accordingly

Comment: I tried using this instead of what EdChum suggested, but it gives `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe0' in position 17: ordinal not in range(128)` (and I get the reason for this error). I tried also  `map(lambda x: str(x.encode('utf-8')), df.columns)`, but it still gives the first error. I think the problem is that I can't get where the _usecols_ comes into play when using read_excel. I looked into the pandas code, but I lose the trail of _usecols_.

Comment: possibly this can help df.columns = map(lambda x: x.encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8'), df.columns)

Comment: it doesn't work. It gives back the error `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe0' in position 17: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: Giacomo Sachs update the solution please try that will work

Answer (score 8):

These methods are really efficient to select Excel columns:

First case using numbers, column "A" = 0, column "B" =  1 etc.

`df = pd.read_excel("filename.xlsx",usecols= range(0,5))`

Second case using letters:

`df = pd.read_excel("filename.xlsx",usecols= "A, C, E:J")`

Answer (score 3):

In case you want to read your excel file by specific column names, follow the following sample code using "usecol":

```
> df = pd.read_excel("filename.xlsx",usecols=["col_name1", "col_name2", "col_name3"])
> print(df)
```

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I was trying to do, but I get the error you can find in the question, because of a column name with an accent character.